# Problems with control statement if...else in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R and here's my code:

```
for (i in 1:7){
testing<-vector(length=(length(yy)-3))
if(all(yy[i:(i+2)]==0))
testing[i]<-1
else
testing[i]<-NA
}
```

`yy` refers to the following vector of length 10:

```
> yy
 [1] 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

`testing` is like a predict function output, which will predict a 1 if the previous 3 elements in `yy` are all 0.If not, it will not predict anything, and so NA. Since `yy` has a total of 10 elements, `testing` will have a total of 7 elements (Therefore length 7)  However, instead of giving me a output of 1s and NAs, it is giving this:

```
> testing
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

I cannot figure out why, some help will be great. Thank you.

Comment: 1. the default mode of vector is logical. 2. I don't think you mean to create `testing` within the loop

Comment: Look at the output of `vector(length=2)`: it's `FALSE FALSE`

Comment: I would suggest using `integer` instead of `vector`. And of course, a vectorized solution would be faster than the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You should define `testing` outside the loop:

```
testing<-vector(length=(length(yy)-3))
for (i in 1:7){
    if(all(yy[i:(i+2)]==0))
        testing[i]<-1
    else
        testing[i]<-NA
}

 testing
[1] NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA
```

For this task you couls also use `rollapply` from `zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(yy, 3, function(x) ifelse(all(x == 0), 1, NA))
[1] NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are some additional vectorized ways of solving this

Base r `stats::filter`

```
N <- 3
NA^(stats::filter(yy == 0, rep(1, N), sides = 1)[-(1:N-1)] != N)
# [1] NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
```

---

`data.table::shift`

```
NA^(Reduce(`+`, data.table::shift(yy == 0, 0:(N-1)))[-(1:N-1)] != N)
# [1] NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
```

---

`RcppRoll::roll_sum`

```
NA^(RcppRoll::roll_sum(yy == 0, N) != N)
# [1] NA  1  1 NA NA NA NA NA
```

---

Some becnmarks (I've also added a compiled version of the for loop using `compiler::cmpfun` and two more efficient `zoo` solutions)

```
ForLoop <- function(yy, N){
  testing<-vector(length=(length(yy)-N))
  for (i in 1:length(testing)){
    if(all(yy[i:(i+(N-1))]==0))
      testing[i]<-1
    else
      testing[i]<-NA
  }
  testing
}

ForLoopBin <- compiler::cmpfun(ForLoop)

ZOO <- function(yy, N) zoo::rollapply(yy, N, function(x) ifelse(all(x == 0), 1, NA))

ZOO2 <- function(yy, N) NA^!zoo::rollapply(yy == 0, N, all)

ZOO3 <- function(yy, N) NA^(zoo::rollsum(yy == 0, N) != N)

RCPPROLL <- function(yy, N) NA^(RcppRoll::roll_sum(yy == 0, N) != N)

BaseFilter <- function(yy, N) NA^(stats::filter(yy == 0, rep(1, N), sides = 1)[-(1:N-1)] != N)

DTShift <- function(yy, N) NA^(Reduce(`+`, data.table::shift(yy == 0, 0:(N-1)))[-(1:N-1)] != N)

set.seed(123)
yy <- sample(0:1, 1e4, replace = TRUE)
N <- 3

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  "for loop" = ForLoop(yy, N),
  "Compiled for loop" = ForLoopBin(yy, N),
  "zoo1" = ZOO(yy, N),
  "zoo2" = ZOO2(yy, N),
  "zoo3" = ZOO3(yy, N),
  "Rcpproll" = RCPPROLL(yy, N),
  "stats::filter" = BaseFilter(yy, N),
  "data.table::shift" = DTShift(yy, N)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#              expr        min         lq        mean      median          uq        max neval    cld
#          for loop  25917.837  26858.936  30157.3927  28546.2595  29334.2430 110135.205   100    d  
# Compiled for loop   7559.837   8208.142   9709.7256   8882.6875   9428.9155  22683.347   100   c   
#              zoo1 101699.548 107857.014 112210.5929 110402.3985 113335.7745 171537.068   100      f
#              zoo2  72265.949  77788.709  81275.9028  80292.8135  81917.8985 153197.948   100     e 
#              zoo3   4584.861   4734.778   4939.3528   4785.9770   4853.6560  13228.514   100  b    
#          Rcpproll    216.636    246.076    290.7211    290.0745    311.3540    663.667   100 a     
#     stats::filter    425.912    475.350    536.0757    509.5900    544.6295   1497.568   100 a     
# data.table::shift    334.394    365.593    443.2138    409.4325    424.6320   1944.279   100 a
```

Comment: @DatamineR and Rcpproll beats them all - it's all about about vectorizations... Even your  `zoo` solution, when vectorized is much faster.